# Parsing Java String into GMT Date

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse a String that represents a date using GMT, but it prints out in my timezone on my PC (pacific).  When I run the below I get the below output.  Any ideas on how to get the parse to parse and return a GMT date?  If you look below I'm setting the timezone using  format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); but its not producing the desired result.

output from below code:

**Mon Oct 29 05:57:00 PDT 2012**

```
 package javaapplication1;

    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.TimeZone;


    public class JavaApplication1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
            format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            System.out.println(format.parse("2012-10-29T12:57:00-0000"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: `-0000` does not necessarily denote GMT. It’s not completely clear what it does denote or whether it’s allowed (according to [the ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) at all. It may mean an undefined offset from UTC. GMT would be denoted either by `Z` or by `+0000` with a plus sign.

Comment: For new readers to this question I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` in the formatter, which is being used in formatting the string into date i.e.

```
      Date date = format.parse("2012-10-29T12:57:00-0000");
```

is parsed treating `2012-10-29T12:57:00-0000` was a `GMT` value, **but you are printing `date` which uses local timezome in printing hence you are noticing the difference.**

If you want to print the date back in `GMT`, please use:

```
    String formattedDate = format.format(date);
```

and print the `formattedDate`. **This will be `GMT`.**

```
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Complete working example

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date())); 
        // ^^^ note printing the results of sdf.format() 
        //     not a raw `Date`
    }
}
```

result : `31-10-2012 08:32:01 UTC`
**Note what I am actually printing out!**

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(format.parse("2012-10-29T12:57:00-0000"));
```

Parses the date as GMT and returns a Date object. Then it prints it out (using the default toString()-method). This just uses the settings of your computer. so you should use:

```
Date parsedDate=format.parse("2012-10-29T12:57:00-0000");
System.out.println(format.format(parsedDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static String converterGMTToLocal(String datahora_gmt)
{
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(fmt.parse(datahora_gmt));
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -3);

        return fmt.format(cal.getTime());

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Change the values for your project...make the appropriate changes

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. I prefer using the following formatter for parsing.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
        .appendPattern("xx")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
```

Parse into an `OffsetDateTime` in order to preserve the offset from the string (`-0000`).

```
    String gmtString = "2012-10-29T12:57:00-0000";
    OffsetDateTime gmtDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(gmtString, PARSER);
    System.out.println(gmtDateTime);
```

Output is:

> 2012-10-29T12:57Z

The trailing `Z` in the output denotes UTC or offset 0 from UTC, which for our purpose we can regard as equivalent to GMT. If we prefer, we can also format back using the same (or a different) formatter before printing:

```
    System.out.println(gmtDateTime.format(PARSER));
```

> 2012-10-29T12:57:00+0000

In this case you will probably want to name the formatter something else than `PARSER`.

### Offset -0000 is not legal

I wonder where you got that string because it adheres to the standard ISO 8601 format except ISO 8601 does not permit `-0000` as an offset. Offset zero must be given as `Z`, `+00:00`, `+0000` or `+00`. Fortunately for us Java is lenient on this point and accepts `-0000` as equivalent to `+0000`.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Question: [What is the difference between UTC and GMT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942916/what-is-the-difference-between-utc-and-gmt)
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)