# MariaDB/MySQL: is the "UTC" timezone the same as "+00:00"?

Tags: mysql, timezone, mariadb, utc

My app has to deal with time zones (fun!). To that end I have decided that in the DB everything will be UTC. For all to work well I need to set the connection timezone:

```
SET time_zone='UTC';
```

There's just one problem - MariaDB comes by default without data in the time zone table, so the above line fails. I can instead use:

```
SET time_zone='+00:00';
```

Which *should* do the same... but does it really? Perhaps there is some weird corner case where the two are not the same and which will come back to haunt me? I can't think of anything, but... I'd like to double-check.

Comment: I'm talking from memory but in the context of MySQL (MariaDB should be similar) named time zones are only required to handle _changes_ in time zone rules (e.g. DST) and don't really accomplish anything else. You know the deal: with `Europe/Madrid` you can figure out whether it's `+01:00` or `+02:00` depending on the date. Nice question anyway.

Comment: Somewhere there are instructions on loading the TZ table(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi yes UTC is the same as +00:00 as both will have no daylight savings changes as they're region-free.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on a corner case. :-) The offset, such as +00;00, could be an offset from either GMT or UTC. So *in theory* it might not be exactly the same as UTC. However, in theory there is never more than 1 second between the two, and in practice I have still to hear of any computer that makes any distinction between the two at all.

So I’d be happy with your second version

```
SET time_zone='+00:00';
```

**Link:** [Difference between UTC and GMT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942916/difference-between-utc-and-gmt)

Comment: Whether MariaDB codebase actually implements leap seconds differently for GMT and UTC is another story :)

Comment: True, @ÁlvaroGonzález. But I doubt it.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it implemented them at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

UTC is in all cases that I know of the reference time, meaning it's +00:00.

Every sites agree on that, you could try to look at sites like this one: https://24timezones.com/time-zone/utc , which indicate the time difference to UTC (+00).