# Scala - How to convert LocalDateTime to ZonedDateTime formatted without GMT postfix?

Tags: java, scala, datetime, time

I wanted to get the LocalDateTime in GMT so wrapped it with ZonedDateTime.

But `gmtZoneTime` is returned in the following format: `2019-10-29T00:00Z[GMT]` While I need it to be: `2019-10-29T00:00:00.000+0000`

How should I properly convert `localDateTime` into the GMT ZonedDateTime?

```
val currentDate:LocalDate = java.time.LocalDate.now
val localDateTime: LocalDateTime = currentDate.atStartOfDay
val gmtZoneTime: ZonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("GMT"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your code is incorrect. When I ran it in my time zone (Europe/Copenhagen) just now, I got

> 2019-10-29T23:00Z[GMT]

I don’t think you intended 23:00 in GMT.

Second you may think of GMT or UTC as an offset (of zero from UTC), so it is more correct to use an `OffsetDateTIme` than a `ZonedDateTime` for the time. This also eliminates your unwanted suffix. In Java (it’s all I can write):

```
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    OffsetDateTime gmtZoneTime = currentDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(gmtZoneTime);
```

Output when running just now:

> 2019-10-30T00:00Z

Edit: You can safely regard UTC and GMT as synonymous since java.time does that (even though strictly speaking they may differ by up to a second).

I assumed you also wanted the date in UTC, so passed this as argument to `LocalDate.now()`. If you want the date in some other time zone, pass that time zone to `LocalDate.now()` so that it is clear from the code what you get.

If you want that specific format in your question, pezetem is correct in the other answer that you need to format into a string:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx");
    String formattedGmtTime = gmtZoneTime.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(formattedGmtTime);
```

> 2019-10-30T00:00:00.000+0000

It seems wordy to me, though. I’d at least leave out the milliseconds since we know they are 0, probably the seconds too. Said without knowing your exact business case.

**Link:** [Difference between UTC and GMT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942916/difference-between-utc-and-gmt)

Comment: You can safely regard UTC and GMT as synonymous. Please see my minor edit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to format the `ZonedDateTime`.

First approach would be to use predefined formatter like: `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`, however for `GMT` it shows 'Z' instead of '+0000' (default behaviour, other offsets are displayed like '+0100' etc.)

So the second one would be to create your own formatter like:
`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")`

and then use it to format `ZonedDateTime` like `gmtZoneTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"))`
so you get a result like:

```
2019-10-28T23:00:00+0000
```