# Current date in GMT with DateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter

I have a problem with the parsing date from the current date to date in GMT timezone.

```
extension Date {
    func getLocalizedDay() -> Date {
       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       var calendar = Calendar.current
       calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")! as TimeZone
       dateFormatter.calendar = calendar
       dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
       dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
       guard let otpDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: self)) else { return Date() }
       return otpDate
    }
}
```

When I print this I get a correct date but in string

```
dateFormatter.string(from: self)
```

When I try to convert it back to date like this:

```
dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: self))
```

I get a date but in UTC...

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

EDIT:

```
var dateFromatter = DateFormatter()
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")! as TimeZone
dateFromatter.calendar = calendar
dateFromatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let now = Date()

let dateInString = dateFromatter.string(from: now)
print(dateInString) // 2020-05-02 13:11:01
print(dateFromatter.date(from: dateInString)!) // 2020-05-02 11:11:01 +0000
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942916/difference-between-utc-and-gmt][1]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't solve my problem. I need to reload data at midnight, but with this time I reload it at 2 AM.

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs? Remember that `Date` objects represent a point in time, an _instant_. It doesn't store any timezone information.

Comment: @Sweeper In edit

Comment: So `2020-05-02 12:53:43` is desired? If so, this is a classic misunderstanding of the `Date` class, and there is probably a duplicate somewhere...

Comment: Yeah that date is desired. Where is a problem?

Comment: See the duplicate. TLDR: you should use a `String` not a `Date`.

Comment: Cant u use Date(), which is a UTC date, pls check

Answer (score 0):

The formulae i know is, when u get a Date object it is always in UTC/GMT.

Whe u are using date formatter , Date -> String , sting u will get is related time zone u set.

When u convert String -> Date, Date wu willget in always in UTC/GMT, no matter what time zone u set.

> ///1 Now is a date in UTC -> converting to UTC date strng right.
>   print(dateFromatter.string(from: now)) // 2020-05-02 12:53:43
>
> ///2 You are converting UTC Date String to Date, which will be in UTC
>   print(dateFromatter.date(from: dateFromatter.string(from: now))!) // 2020-05-02 10:53:43 +0000

Comment: Is there any way how to convert string date to correct date of ty Date() ?