# Is GMT and UTC same for ZonedDateTime?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, java-time, zoneddatetime

I've implemented an API for International use and I'm trying to return dates of objects in GMT Time ,in ISO 8601 format. Right now I do this by

```
ZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

But I do know that UTC and GMT are not the same thing.

Later I will be assigning every user with their preferred Locale and return with their Locale , but now I want to do this as GMT , but I don't know how to do It the right way

Comment: GMT and UTC are the same thing. GMT+0 is the same as UCT+0

Comment: @Matt So do I not need to do anything about ""Neither UTC nor GMT ever change for Daylight Saving Time (DST). However, some of the countries that use GMT switch to different time zones during their DST period.

For example, the United Kingdom is not on GMT all year, it uses British Summer Time (BST), which is one hour ahead of GMT, during the summer months."" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between UTC and GMT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942916/difference-between-utc-and-gmt)

Comment: UTC and GMT are the same.
I would suggest using a timezone library that allows you to declare a locale and then fetch a date and no longer have to worry about this. The only one I am aware of is the Timezone Util, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html

The only other alternative is to adjust the timezone based on daylight-savings. Where some people do not live in countries with such things.

Comment: @Matt, you’re completely on the wrong track with `TimeZone`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. The OP is wisely using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. S/he should use `ZoneId` from that API.

Comment: @texasbruce Your jshell output shows that a little over 3 seconds passed between your first two commands. It does not show that GMT and UTC are different.

Comment: @texasbruce The OP already says *I do know that UTC and GMT are not the same thing.*, so no, this question is not a duplicate of that one. This question is asking specifically about `ZonedDateTime`, which is only mentioned sporadically in one of the answers there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

To a `ZonedDateTime` UTC and GMT have different names but the same zone rules, so the time will always be the same in UTC and in GMT.

### Theory

Originally GMT and UTC were defined differently. There were never more than a second between the UTC time and the GMT time. As UTC has become the ubiquitous anchor of time, GMT is sometimes used loosely to mean UTC, so the distinction is more blurred.

### Practice: ZonedDateTme

A `ZonedDateTime` uses a `ZoneId` for its time zone, so your question is equal to asking whether to `ZoneId` GMT and UTC are the same. Let’s for a start see how they may look:

```
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC");
    System.out.println("Etc/UTC:        " + utc);

    ZoneId gmt = ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT");
    System.out.println("Etc/GMT:        " + gmt);

    ZoneId utcNormalized = utc.normalized();
    System.out.println("UTC normalized: " + utcNormalized);

    ZoneOffset utcAsOffset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
    System.out.println("UTC as offset:  " + utcAsOffset);

    ZoneId gmtNormalized = gmt.normalized();
    System.out.println("GMT normalized: " + gmtNormalized);
```

Output is:

> ```
> Etc/UTC:        Etc/UTC
> Etc/GMT:        Etc/GMT
> UTC normalized: Z
> UTC as offset:  Z
> GMT normalized: Z
> ```

The first two lines show us that `ZoneId` can indeed distinguish between GMT and UTC. They are both valid time zones with each their time zone ID.

The `normalized()` method that I use for the 3rd and 5th lines promises to convert a `ZoneId` to a `ZoneOffset` *if* the time zone uses a constant offset. In both cases we get an offset of zero back. So here `ZoneId` does not distinguish.

To check the matter even more closely:

```
    System.out.println("Are GMT and UTC the same? " + utc.equals(gmt));
    System.out.println("Are GMT and UTC the same? "
            + utcNormalized.equals(gmtNormalized));
    System.out.println("Are GMT and UTC the same? "
            + utc.getRules().equals(utcAsOffset.getRules()));
```

> ```
> Are GMT and UTC the same? false
> Are GMT and UTC the same? true
> Are GMT and UTC the same? true
> ```

So the `ZoneId` objects are not equal, and `ZonedDateTime` objects using the two will not be equal either even when they have the same date and time. But we get the same offset from them and they have equal zone rules, that is, they will always have the same time.

### Consequences in Java code

This line is from your question:

```
ZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

This is correct and there is no compelling reason why you should want to do otherwise. If you prefer, since Java regards UTC as a zone offset, you may convert to an `OffsetDateTime` instead. I somehow regard it as less heavy-weight than `ZonedDateTime`.

If you want your `ZonedDateTime` to print in GMT rather than UTC, use `ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT")`. Here I am using my variable from before holding that time zone:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdtGmt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Istanbul"))
            .withZoneSameInstant(gmt);
    System.out.println("Time in GMT: " + zdtGmt);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL)
            .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("tr"));
    System.out.println("Time in GMT: " + zdtGmt.format(formatter));
```

Output just now:

> ```
> Time in GMT: 2020-05-16T09:34:05.253696Z[Etc/GMT]
> Time in GMT: 16 Mayıs 2020 Cumartesi 09:34:05 Greenwich Ortalama Saati
> ```

You further wrote:

> Later I will be assigning every user with their preferred Locale and
>   return with their Locale …

`Locale` is not relevant here. Locale and time zone are orthogonal concepts. A person from Turkey visiting Shanghai may for example want to use Turkish locale and Shanghai time zone. There is no way to deduce a time zone from a locale (at least no sound way). You will probably want to consider assigning each user a preferred time zone.