# How to append GMT+ to datetime object in python

Tags: python, django

I have a datetime filed in my `models.py` and another field that saves the selected timezone as well `(like Asia/Tehran)`.
I need to append the the `utc` info of this timezone to my datetime object like this:
`'20/4/2021 18:33:00 Gmt+4:30`
How can i do that?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I don't know which function i need to use to give me the "GMT+4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code, replace the numbers with your specified date in your GMT+4.5 timezone.

```
import datetime
timezone_diff = datetime.timedelta(hours=4.5)   
GMT_timezone = datetime.timezone(timezone_diff, name="GMT")
GMT_time = datetime.datetime(2017,2,14,12,15,1,99,GMT_timezone,fold=1)

print('{0:%d}/{0:%m}/{0:%Y} {0:%H:%M:%S} {0:%Z}{0:%z}'.format(GMT_time))
```

See results:
[image]

Comment: Tnx but how can create that GMT+1 according to my timezone field?this field can get different timezones

Comment: First, know that GMT and UTC are the same, they differ on some application. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942916/difference-between-utc-and-gmt 

If you plan to convert your timezone, in Tehran, you are GMT+4:30, you should make some adjustment. Let me see if I can code for you.

Comment: Modified the code with your preferred conversion.

Comment: Your welcome. Don't forget to upvote the answer. Thanks as well.